# In Amcharts4 range.contents.fill doesn't work with Lineseries.propertiesField.fill

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

In a Amcharts4 line chart, the chart fill color comes from 2 different places. Lineseries.propertyFields.fill and range.contents.fill.

I get a the color Hex value used by Lineseries.propertyFields.fill from a Ajax Call.

part of the back-end code:

```
if (temps == "2020-08-11T07:15:00.000Z") {Color = "#5476ff"};
    JSlist.add(["value":prod,"date":temps,"lineColor":Color]);
    writeJSON("myJSONAnswer": JSlist);
```

I then use `series.propertyFields.fill = "lineColor";` to color specific areas of the graph.
This works well.

```
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.fillOpacity = 0.5;
series.propertyFields.stroke = "lineColor";
series.propertyFields.fill = "lineColor";
```

though I also want to color other ranges of the graph using `range.contents.fill = am4core.color("#808080");`

```
var range = dateAxis.createSeriesRange(series);
range.date = new Date("2020-08-11T09:00:00.000Z");
range.endDate = new Date("2020-08-11T09:30:00.000Z");
range.contents.stroke = am4core.color("#808080");
range.contents.fill = am4core.color("#808080");
range.contents.fillOpacity = 0.6;
//https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/axis-ranges/#Using_with_series
```

If I comment these 3 lines, I can see the colored range. Otherwise it's overridden by it.

```
series.fillOpacity = 0.5;
series.propertyFields.stroke = "lineColor";
series.propertyFields.fill = "lineColor";
```

I want `range.contents.fill = am4core.color("#808080");` to override `series.propertyFields.stroke = "lineColor";`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I tried implementing your Amcharts code and it seems to be able to display the range just fine, although I have to change `range.contents.fillOpacity` value to `1` in order for it to be noticeable.

Try running the snippet and see if this is what you intended.

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

var data = [];
var value = 50;
for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++){
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  date.setDate(i);
  value -= Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 10);
  data.push({date:date, value: value, lineColor: "#5476ff"});
}

chart.data = data;

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 60;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.tooltipText = "{value}"
series.fillOpacity = 0.5;
series.propertyFields.stroke = "lineColor";
series.propertyFields.fill = "lineColor";

var range = dateAxis.createSeriesRange(series);
range.date = new Date("2020-08-11T09:00:00.000Z");
range.endDate = new Date("2020-10-11T09:30:00.000Z");
range.contents.stroke = am4core.color("#808080");
range.contents.fill = am4core.color("#808080");
range.contents.fillOpacity = 1;

series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series;
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

EDIT: You can override the `propertyFields` property of series by creating a "ready" event listener and replacing the `range.content` colors AFTER the chart has been rendered.

```js
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

var data = [];
var value = 50;
for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++){
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  date.setDate(i);
  value -= Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 10);
  data.push({date:date, value: value, lineColor: "#5476ff", rangeColor: "#000000"});
}

chart.data = data;

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 60;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.tooltipText = "{value}"
series.fillOpacity = 0.5;
series.propertyFields.stroke = "lineColor";
series.propertyFields.fill = "lineColor";

var range = dateAxis.createSeriesRange(series);
range.date = new Date("2020-08-11T09:00:00.000Z");
range.endDate = new Date("2020-10-11T09:30:00.000Z");
range.contents.stroke = am4core.color("#808080");
range.contents.fillOpacity = 1;

series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series;
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;

//Event listener to replace the content color after chart has been rendered, thus overriding propertyFields
chart.events.on("ready", () =>{
    range.contents.children.values.forEach(item => {
      item.stroke = am4core.color("#808080");
      item.fill = am4core.color("#808080");
    });
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer! That proofs we can use the "range" to override fill.opacity but not the acutal fill color, #808080 being grey. We're still with series.propertyFields.fill = "lineColor" with opacity 1 instead of 0.5. Could be a ok workaround. Better if I can change the actual color though.

Comment: My bad, I did not notice the #808080 being grey, thanks for pointing that out. Did some additional research on this and found out the reason this happens is due to `propertyFields` being rendered last, so anything set with this will override other states. This also explains why `fillOpacity` works, because it is set directly as a series state instead of `propertyFields`

Comment: ok, thanks. You can think of a workaround other than adjusting opacity?

Comment: You could add an event listener to fire on "ready" event (after chart has been rendered) and iterate through range.content child elements to replace the colors. I have updated the answer with the new workaround.